# puzzled by xlim/ylim behavior in R

Tags: r

R-3.1.1, Win7x64

Hi, I have data where two variables are measured such that X runs from 0 to 70 and Y runs from 0 to 100. I want to make a simple scatterplot of the observations. 
The scatterplot should be dimensionalized, such that the x-axis (running from 0-70) is .7 the size of the y-axis (which runs from 0-100).

I use the following code

```
plot.new()
plot(0, 0, asp = 1, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "n")
```

I am surprised to see that this yields a graph as follows:
[image]

Two things are not how I expected it: 1) the x-axis and y-axis are NOT restricted to their xlim and ylim values. (Why is that?) and 2) the figure is almost square.

I can resize the figure manually, by manually resizing the R window or the Rstudio window before using the code, but that is not feasible, because I have a great many figures to draw, many with varying xlim and ylim sizes and these figures need to be inserted into preformatted reports later (which is why they need to fulfill these exact layout demands). 
I have also tried using

```
dev.new(width = 7, height = 10)
```

but that didn't help either.

My question is:
1) how can I "force" the figure to be restriced to the exact xlim and ylim ranges passed to the function?
and 
2) how to generate a figure with the exact relative dimensions (the x-axis being .7 times as wide as the length of the y-axis)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The discussion of `asp` in the help for `plot.window` implies that `asp` will override `xlim` and `ylim` settings (if you look at the help for `plot`, it directs you to `plot.window` to find out more about `asp`):

> If `asp` is a finite positive value then the window is set up so that
>   one data unit in the x direction is equal in length to `asp` * one data
>   unit in the y direction.
>
> Note that in this case, `par("usr")` is no longer determined by, e.g.,
>   `par("xaxs")`, but rather by `asp` and the device's aspect ratio. (See
>   what happens if you interactively resize the plot device after running
>   the example below!)
>
> The special case `asp == 1` produces plots where distances between
>   points are represented accurately on screen. Values with `asp > 1` can
>   be used to produce more accurate maps when using latitude and
>   longitude.

As @mr.joshuagordon noted, you can use the `pdf` (or `png` or `jpeg` if you want bitmap output) function and play with the dimensions to get the aspect ratio you want, while removing the `asp` argument from `plot` so that you can set the `xlim` and `ylim` values.

Another option is to switch to `ggplot2`, which makes it easy to set axis limits and aspect ratio separately:

```
library(ggplot2) 

# Some fake data
dat = data.frame(x=c(2,30,50), y=c(10, 60, 90))

# 1 y-unit = 1 x-unit, so the plot area is not square
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,70)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=1)  

# 1 y-unit = 0.7 * 1 x-unit, so the plot is square, but the physical distance
# of each x-unit and y-unit are no longer the same
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,70)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=70/100)
```

**UPDATE:** Here's how to control `xlim`, `ylim` and the aspect ratio independently in base graphics: Instead of `asp`, use the graphical parameter `pin` to set the physical dimensions of the plot region. This setting does not affect the nominal values of `xlim` and `ylim`, but will change the physical distance measure of 1 x-unit and 1 y-unit. Here are some examples:

Example 1: We'll create two panels on one PDF page, each with a different aspect ratio:

```
# Create a 12" x 6" pdf graphics device 
pdf("test.pdf", width=12, height=6)

# Divide graphics device into two regions, each of which will contain a plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

# Left Panel: 5" x 5" plot area (plot region is square, so 1 y-unit = 
# 0.7 * 1 x-unit in terms of physical distance in the plot region)
par(pin=c(5,5))
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n",main='par(pin=c(5,5)')

# Right Panel: 0.7*5" x 5" plot area (so 1 x-unit = 1 y-unit 
# in terms of physical distance in the plot region)
par(pin=c(0.7*5,5))
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n",main='par(pin=c(5,0.7*5)')

dev.off()
```

Example 2: Showing that you'll get an error if you set `pin` to be larger than the size of the graphics device. We'll use the default device (`RStudioGD` in my case).

```
par(pin=c(10, 10))
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n",main='par(pin=c(5,4)')

# Get dimensions of the default plot device 
par("din") 

# Create a plot that takes up an area just a bit smaller than the device size
par(pin=par("din")-0.2)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n",main='par(pin=c(5,4)')

# Create a plot that takes up an area just a bit larger than the device size 
# (we'll get an error this time)
par(pin=par("din") + 0.01)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n")

> Error in plot.new() : plot region too large
```

Example 3: The same error occurs if you exceed the size of your `pdf` (or `png`, etc.) device:

```
# Create a 5" x 5" pdf graphics device
pdf("test.pdf", 5,5)
# Create a plot that takes up a little bit less than the device size
par(pin=c(5,5)-0.2)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n")
dev.off()

# Create a plot that takes up a little bit more than the device size
pdf("test.pdf", 5,5)
par(pin=c(5,5)+0.01)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     type = "n")
# Gives the following error: Error in plot.new() : plot region too large
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for adding to @mr.joshuagordon's answer. This explains why it didn't work, although I still find it puzzling why xlim and ylim would need to be overridden by asp. In my case, I do need asp (since 1 x-step is exactlly equal to 1 y-step, as they represent metres in the data), but I also want to be able to restrict the plot to the data range I am working with.

Thanks for the ggplot2 solution, it seems like I have to finally start learning ggplot2...

Comment: I highly recommend learning `ggplot2`. I avoided it for a while also, because it seemed like a lot of work to learn a new way of thinking about graphics. But it didn't take that long and I rarely use base graphics any more.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10, you have been extremely helpful The updates to your answer are VERY useful and you are certainly stimulating me to pickup ggplot2. One reason why I have resisted it so far, is that it appears much slower to render the graphics than base graphics.

Comment: I've found `ggplot2` to be slower also, but the difference is unnoticeable until you get to very large data sets (at least a million rows in my experience--well, maybe a million rows isn't so large anymore). But if that's an issue, just use `dplyr` (or your favorite `R` split-apply-combine strategy) to do the aggregation and summary and then feed the summary data to `ggplot2`. Also, Hadley Wickham (ggplot2's creator) has been working on ways to quickly plot huge data sets, so I would expect any speed differential to decline over time.

Comment: That is good to know. I am glad to hear that Hadley is working on speeding up ggplot2. At this point, I expect that finding the time to learn ggplot2 will be slower than ggplot2 itself :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can save the plot as a pdf and specify its dimensions as follows:

```
pdf("SampleGraph.pdf",width=7,height=10)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 70), ylim = c(0, 100), asp=NA, xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "n") # change asp to NA
dev.off() # turn off plotting
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I would prefer to do this without haveing to write to a separate file, but this does solve the problem effectively, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

plot(..., xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To format things as code you can use the button in the editor, or wrap the text in single back ticks for inline, or precede and follow with a line with three back ticks, or indent with four spaces. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.