# R: par(mfg) resets ylim values

Tags: r, plot, par

I'm having a frustrating experience trying to use par(mfg) to move between subplots of a figure.  It seems like changing which plot I'm working in using this command resets something about the way y axes are specified such that the ylim=c(a,b) call is useless. This thread ([puzzled by xlim/ylim behavior in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583189/puzzled-by-xlim-ylim-behavior-in-r)) makes me believe that asp may play a role here, but I can't figure out how or how to correct the error.

Briefly, to plot results from density() for multiple datasets on two subplots of a single window, I've written a loop that increments through two lists of output from density() adding new lines to subplot 1, then subplot 2, then back to subplot 1, etc.

```
DATA.A<-vector("list",length=6)
DATA.B<-vector("list",length=6)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(0,0, main="title", xlab="X", ylab="Y", xlim=c(c,d), ylim=c(0,30))
plot(0,0, main="title", xlab="X", ylab="Y", xlim=c(c,d), ylim=c(-5,5))

 for(i in 1:6){ 

    DATA.A[[i]]<-density(RAWDATA.A[[i]][,"varname"], from=c, to=d, by=e)
    DATA.B[[i]]<-density(RAWDATA.B[[i]][,"varname"], from=c, to=d, by=e)

    par(mfg=c(1,1))
    lines(DATA.A[[i]]$x,DATA.A[[i]]$y,ylim=c(0,30),col="black", lty=i)
    lines(DATA.B[[i]]$x,DATA.B[[i]]$y,ylim=c(0,30),col="red", lty=i)

    par(mfg=c(2,1))
    lines(DATA.A[[i]]$x,DATA.B[[i]]$y-DATA.A[[i]]$y,
        ylim=c(-5,5), col="red", lty=i)
    abline(v=median(RAWDATA.A[[i]][,"varname"]),lty=i, col="black")
}
```

EDIT: I am realizing that it fails mostly for the first subplot where it is supposed to be plotting densities over the range from 0 to 30, but instead always resets the axis to the range -1 to 1. Calling plot(0,0), the y tick labels correspond to ylim values I provide, but the data is plotted on the -1 to 1 range.  I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you should save the par() settings from the first (and second) plot calls and then restore them before you use lines().

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @BondedDust. When I try this, I find that it plots the data from subplot 1 in the subplot 2 window, but it looks like it is over the correct scale!  Getting closer, I think!