# Why can't I adjust the vertical range of a plot by ylim() with igraph in R?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm trying to draw three DAGs in a row:

```
library(igraph)

CENTERS <- rbind(c(-10,0),c(10,0),c(0,10))
g1 <- graph(c(2,1), n=2)
V(g1)$label <- c("X","Y")
g2 <- graph(c(2,1, 1,3, 2,3), n=3)
V(g2)$label <- c("X","Y","Z")
g3 <- graph(c(1,3, 2,3), n=3)
V(g3)$label <- c("X","Y","Z")

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(g1, layout=CENTERS[1:2,], axes = TRUE, rescale=FALSE, 
     xlim=c(-15,15), ylim=c(-5,15),
     edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.color="black", edge.width=1,
     vertex.label=V(g1)$label, vertex.color="bisque", vertex.size=400,
     main = "Purely Causal", sub="(A)")
plot(g2, layout=CENTERS, axes = FALSE, rescale=FALSE, 
     xlim=c(-15,15), ylim=c(-5,15),
     edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.color="black", edge.width=1,
     vertex.label=V(g2)$label, vertex.color="white", vertex.size=400,
     main = "Generic", sub="(B)")
plot(g3, layout=CENTERS, axes = FALSE, rescale=FALSE, 
     xlim=c(-15,15), ylim=c(-5,15),
     edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.color="black", edge.width=1,
     vertex.label=V(g3)$label, vertex.color="darkolivegreen1", vertex.size=400,
     main = "Purely Confounded", sub="(C)")
```

And it gives this:

[image]

Why isn't `ylim(-5,15)` working? How can I reduce the vertical range of these plots?

---

P.S

I figured that there're probably some better ways to draw DAGs. But this is for a homework, so I kinda need to stick to the igraph package in R.

Comment: Before your `par` statement, try running `dev.new(width=10, height=3, unit="in")`

Comment: @G5W Thanks. A new window popped out, but the y-range is still [-40,60]. So the `ylim( )` just doesn't work?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583189/puzzled-by-xlim-ylim-behavior-in-r) might be helpful. In short, the ylim parameter gets overwritten by the size of the viewer panel. You can try it by making (dragging) the viewer wider and you'll see how the range of the y-axis changes.

Comment: My comment was trying to change the window size as in @BenNutzer 's comment.  When the window opened was it a different size than usual?

Comment: @BenNutzer Thanks a lot! It did change a little bit, not enough though. I think I'll download it anyway and remove some blank area manually.

Comment: @G5W Yes, I changed the window size, and the y-axis gets a bit shorter. Is it possible to download the plot as .eps?