# Unequal spacing between x and y axis (R plot)

Tags: r, plot, spacing

Here's a very simple code.

```
x <- -10:10
b0 <- 0
b1 <- 1.5
y <- rnorm(length(x), b0+b1*x, 10)
plot(y~x)
```

Now, what I get is this plot below.

[image]

As we can see, the spacing on axes is different.
For example, the spacing between 0 and 5 on x-axis is much bigger than the one between 0 and 10 on y-axis. 
I don't understand why this happens and how I can fix it. 
Any comments are highly appreciated!!

(+) I also tried changing the plotting window. However this is the result... **Still... spacing is different!**

[image]

I additionally tried

```
plot(x, y, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-20, 20))
```

It didn't help...

(+) I tried

```
plot(y~x, asp = 1, xlim = c(-20, 20))
```

And this is now what I got: **(xlim function is now NOT working properly.)**
[image]

Comment: Hi @DanY ! On the second figure (that I uploaded), the spacing (or length) between 0 and 5 on x-axis is same as the spacing between 0 and 10 on y-axis. Shouldn't the former proportionally be shorter than the latter?

Comment: Use `asp=1` as in `plot(..., asp=1)`

Comment: @DanY plot(y~x, asp = 1, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-20, 20)) I tried this code, but now, the xlim and ylim functions are not working properly.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583189/puzzled-by-xlim-ylim-behavior-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to the nature of your data. And its obvious and correct and reflects your data. Your data on y axis are between -20 and 20.
For example try  `x <- -3:3`.

You can tweak and modify the axis as suggested in the comments and answers, but as you use `rnorm` the ticks of the axis will change each time you run the code. Because you are generating each time new values.